# android parse URL in a webview

Tags: android, parsing, url, webview

i load a page in a webview and i want to parse the URL that is inside the webview.

this is my code for load the page, using httppost.

The URL is URL FEED: http:/www.ilias.de/docu/feed.php...........

this code make a httppost request and execute the response then it shows the webpage into the webview.

```
public class ilias extends Activity {

 WebView webView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://www.ilias.de/docu/login.php?client_id=docu");
        List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "stacked")); //this username 
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "overflow"));//works


  try {
   UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
         request.setEntity(entity);

         HttpResponse response= httpClient.execute(request);

   bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
   StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
   String line = "";
   String LineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
   while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuffer.append(line + LineSeparator); 
   }
   bufferedReader.close();

   Toast.makeText(ilias.this, 
     "Finished", 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   String webData = stringBuffer.toString();

   webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); 
   webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

   webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.ilias.de/docu/",webData,"text/html","UTF-8","about:blank");
   String postData = "username=stacked&password=overflow";
   String url = "http://www.ilias.de/docu/login.php?client_id=docu";

  webView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "base64"));

  webView.loadUrl("http://www.ilias.de/docu/ilias.php?col_side=left&block_type=pdnews&cmd=showFeedUrl&cmdClass=ilpdnewsblockgui&cmdNode=i7:db:le&baseClass=ilPersonalDesktopGUI");
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
      handler.proceed() ;
      }
     });

  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(ilias.this, 
     e.toString(), 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   Toast.makeText(ilias.this, 
     e.toString(), 
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }finally{
   if (bufferedReader != null){
    try {
     bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }


    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish what you are looking for by using [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) inside of your WebViewClient.

EX:

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
           public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                 handler.proceed() ;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url){
                  //Code to parse url
                  return false;
           }
    });
```

Comment: pd. i dont want to click the link. just parse when page loads